# d3js v5 + topojson v3 Center a square centroid with zoom

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I try to put a square on the center of the geographical entity.
I added orange circles to mark the position of the centroids.

With  a **scale extent = 1** (no zoom), the square's position is correct.
[image]

However, with a **scale extent > 1** (with zoom), there is a translation of the square's position.
[image]

I assume the problem occurs when I define the square's position.

```
let ctrSquare = g.attr("class","ctr_square")
    .selectAll(".ctr_square")
    .data(featureCollectionZe.features)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", (d)=>{return path.centroid(d)[0] - 7/2;})
    .attr("y", (d)=>{return path.centroid(d)[1] - 7/2;})
    .attr("width",7)
    .attr("height",7)
    .attr("fill","#0000ff")
    .attr("stroke","#0000ff");
```

Here is my code : https://plnkr.co/edit/K0k9ACxFWgzsqzHmQHmM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you want to keep rectangle size independent of current scale. So, during `.on("zoom", ...)` you modify the rects `width` and `height`:

```
ctrSquare
    .attr("width",7/d3.event.transform.k)
    .attr("height",7/d3.event.transform.k);
```

Taking that into account, the correct code for their `x` and `y` position is following:

```
ctrSquare
    .attr("x",d => path.centroid(d)[0] - 7/d3.event.transform.k/2)
    .attr("y",d => path.centroid(d)[1] - 7/d3.event.transform.k/2)
```

So just add these lines into `.on("zoom", ...)`.

Comment: Indeed! Thank you for your clarification :)